# Explanation of strange output from template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, sfinae

Can someone explain the strange output here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
constexpr auto has_foo_impl(int) -> decltype(typename T::foo{}, std::true_type{});

template <typename T>
constexpr auto has_foo_impl(long) -> std::false_type;

template <typename T>
constexpr bool has_foo() { return decltype(has_foo_impl<T>(0))::value; }

template <typename...> struct rank;

template <typename First, typename... Rest>
struct rank<First, Rest...> : rank<Rest...> {};

template <> struct rank<> {};

template <typename T, typename... Rest, typename... Args>
auto check (rank<T, Rest...>, Args... args) -> std::enable_if_t<has_foo<T>(), decltype(T(args...))> {
    return T(args...);
}

//template <typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
//auto check (rank<T,U>, Args... args) -> std::enable_if_t<has_foo<T>(), decltype(T(args...))> {
//  return T(args...);
//}
//
//template <typename T, typename... Args>
//auto check (rank<T>, Args... args) -> std::enable_if_t<has_foo<T>(), decltype(T(args...))> {
//  return T(args...);
//}

template <typename... Args>
auto check (rank<>, Args...) { std::cout << "Nothing found.\n"; }

template <typename... Ts>
struct Factory {
    template <typename... Args>
    decltype(auto) create (Args... args) const {
        return check(rank<Ts...>{}, args...);
    }
};

struct Object {};

struct Thing {};

struct Blob {
    using foo = int;
    Blob (int, double) { print(); }
    void print() const { std::cout << "Blob\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Factory<Blob, Object, Thing>().create(4,3.5);  // Blob
    Factory<Object, Blob, Thing>().create(4,3.5);  // Nothing found
    Factory<Object, Thing, Blob>().create(4,3.5);  // Nothing found
}
```

I expect to see `Blob` outputted three times.  When I uncomment the commented-out overloads `check`, I do get that though.  Shouldn't the single variadic `check` function take care of the ones I commented out?  After all, `rank<First, Rest...>` derives from `rank<Rest...>`.

I know of other ways to get the same job done, but I'm wondering why this ranking method does not work here.  That `Nothing found` is outputted means that `rank<>` was passed, which means the intermediate ranks were passed too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only get one bite at the cherry.

When performing overload resolution, each available function template gets its template arguments deduced only once, even if SFINAE removes the deduced overload and there might be other (less preferred) ways to deduce the template arguments.

So, given:

```
template <typename T, typename... Rest, typename... Args>
auto check (rank<T, Rest...>, Args... args) -> std::enable_if_t<has_foo<T>(), decltype(T(args...))>;
```

with `rank<Object, Blob, Thing>` as the first argument type, `T` is deduced as `Object` and `Rest` as `[Blob, Thing]`. Only after that does SFINAE kick in and remove the deduced overload.

The fact that uncomment your commented-out overloads makes it work is pure coincidence, simply because that gives 3 function templates, making it work with `Blob` in the first, second-last and last positions; and you've tested it with 3 arguments. It won't work for `Object, Blob, Thing, Whatever` with `Blob` in the 2nd position of 4. ([Example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1619c6ddb43adf31))

Also, uncommenting your commented-out overloads won't work at all in clang, which appears to rank template deduction against inheritance slightly differently. ([Example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d10cde34c85e661))

You need to generate more opportunities for template argument deduction; one way might be recursion ([Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/421c8326c85fd387)):

```
template <typename T, typename... Rest, typename... Args>
auto check (rank<T, Rest...>, Args... args) -> std::enable_if_t<!has_foo<T>(), decltype(check(rank<Rest...>{}, args...))> {
    return check(rank<Rest...>{}, args...);
}
```

Comment: @ ecatmur   Thanks for a very nice answer.  You might be interested in this follow-up question that seems fairly mysterious to answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611105/why-template-instantiations-go-on-forever-here